# How to clone a CentOS server to a VM?

Tags: centos, vmware, clonezilla

I have a HP Proliant DL380 CentOS 5.10 server that I'd like to clone to a VMWare VM. I have successfully cloned it to identical hardware using Clonezilla, however when I try to restore it to a VM it appears to clone successfully, but on boot I get an error message:

[image]

I can't find much information on how to perform a clone like this and I think I might be missing something. The maximum ram I can safely set is 4GB (the server has 12) and maximum cpus is 4 (server has 8).

Answer (score 3):

A problem that I often encountered when cloning from a physical to a virtual machine is that the initrd is often not appropriate anymore.

You should boot your VM on another OS, using a livecd or whatever, then :

- mount your centos root partition to /mnt, and other partitions to appropriate subdirectory
- bind mount /dev, /sys and /proc to /mnt/dev, /mnt/sys and /mnt/proc
- chroot into /mnt
- verify that there is nothing innapropriate in your /etc/modprobe.conf and modprobe.d and that necessary modules are present
- then regenerate your initrd with mkinitrd :

mkinitrd -f /boot/initrd-XXX.img XXX

(where XXX is your kernel version)

And reboot normally to your CentOS.

Sorry that this is a bit vague, I'm telling this by memory.

Comment: What do you mean boot my VM on another OS?

Comment: I mean boot from some live media such as a SystemRescueCD livecd or whatever distribution you fancy so you can fix your system from it.

Comment: I tried running mkinitrd but it ran with several errors.